# Calculate driving distances Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

For a website where a user enters his address, I'm trying to find the location closest to him where the user can collect the ordered goods.

Based on the user's address I can narrow down the possible pick up locations to between 2 and 5. So I'd like to calculate the distance between user's address (point A) and the possible pick up locations.

The demo [here](http://briancray.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/distance.html) works fine with just two addresses. I've adapted the code as much as I can to work with more than two addresses. I posted my JS code [here](http://jsbin.com/uyodo4/edit) since I can't seem to properly format it in SO.

In the code are two alerts. The first alert correctly shows the different pick up locations. But the second alert always shows the LAST pickup location.

Can anyone explain why?

---

HTML:

```
<p id="hello">Hello World</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var geocoder, location1, location2, gDir;

function initialize(counter) {    
    if( counter == 0 ){
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        gDir = new GDirections();
    }
    GEvent.addListener(gDir, "load", function() {
        var drivingDistanceMiles = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1609.344;
        var drivingDistanceKilometers = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;
        $("#results").append('<strong>Driving Distance: </strong>' + drivingDistanceKilometers + ' kilometers<br /><br />');        
    });
}

function getDistance(agency_add, counter) {
    initialize(counter);
    geocoder.getLocations(agency_add, function (response) {    
        if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
            alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the address" + agency_add);
        }
        else {
            location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
            //alert("ONE: "+location1.address);
            geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].address1.value, function (response) {
                //alert("TWO: "+location1.address);
                if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the second address");}
                else {                        
                    location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};                    
                    gDir.load('from: ' + location1.address + ' to: ' + location2.address);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    //put each agency address in an array
    var agencies = [];    
    $(".agency_field").each(function(index) {
        agencies.push($(this).val());
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < agencies.length; i++){
        var res = getDistance(agencies[i], i);
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling geocoder.getLocations inside a loop. geocoder.getLocations runs asynchronously. when it receives the 2nd request while still processing the first, it cancels the first request.

If you want to multi-thread geocoder.getLocations you need to create multiple instances of it.